# Proxy error while django installation on python 3.7 in windows

Tags: python, django, windows

I am trying to install **django** in windows 10. I have already installed **Python 3.7** and running this command to install **django**.

```
pip install django
```

As only Python 3 is installed on my PC, so I didn't have to use `pip3`.

**Error:**

```
Proxy Error() Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refuses it.
```

From the error, I can see it is some kind of proxy error and ask me to change or provide a proxy. But I am not using any proxy and my Firewall is all set (it is not blocking it).

**Tried for solution**

I have already searched it a lot and most of them recommended me to provide `--proxy` with `pip` but I can't, as I am not using any **proxy**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can be caused if you are using some kind of VPN as they are intended to change proxy automatically sometimes.

**For Windows**

Make sure to check your firewall being watched by anti-virus if you have one.
Secondly, you need to check your internet connection settings

```
`Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN settings
```

In **LAN settings dialogue**, under the **Proxy server** menu, Uncheck **Use a proxy server for your LAN…**.